# How do I access DataContext from another class in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a class so I can query my data. If I do it in the controller class data context works, but if I do it in my created class it throws null error.  It throws the following error:

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll but was not handled in user code

My startup config:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddDbContext<Abstractor_DataContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDatabase")));

    //services.AddTransient(typeof(Abstractor_DataContext));


    //Register your filter as a service (Note this filter need not be an attribute as such)
    services.AddTransient<AppExceptionFilterAttribute>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

My class function to access the DataContext

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
public static IList<ApplicationInfo> TestDb()
{
    //var options = _serviceProvider.GetService<Abstractor_DataContext>();
    using (var context = _serviceProvider.GetService<Abstractor_DataContext>())
    {
        return context.ApplicationInfo.ToList();
    }
}
```

`var context` is null.  What am I missing? I am slowly learning DI.

Comment: You are not taking DbContext as input so it can not provide you with the DbContext object.

Comment: When are you using this `TestDb` method? If the data context has been registered by the time you call this method then it should work. But if in example you are calling this during database `Seed` it won't work.

Comment: Ephraim, I am calling it in my control.  
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("GetTestDb")]
            public IList<ApplicationInfo> GetTestDb(int id)
            {
               return DataAccessServices.TestDb();//_context.ApplicationInfo.ToList();
            }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html) for new DB based ASP.net core project, first you need to create your Models and DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models
{
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, register your context with dependency injection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Then create your database using database migrations. Now you create your controller with your constructor taking your context as one of the parameter (Note `BloggingContext context` in the constructor parameter).

```
using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Controllers
{
    public class BlogsController : Controller
    {
        private BloggingContext _context;

        public BlogsController(BloggingContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Blogs.ToList());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Blog blog)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Blogs.Add(blog);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(blog);
        }

    }
}
```

Using DbContext in any class is same using it in controller. You will need to register your class to Dependency injector. It is done in `ConfigureServices` method. [This page from official docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html) is containing the details. Following are some of the examples to register the service class implementations:

```
services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
services.AddScoped<IOperationScoped, Operation>();
services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingleton, Operation>();
services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingletonInstance>(new Operation(Guid.Empty));
services.AddTransient<OperationService, OperationService>();
```

Comment: OP wants to access the context outside of the controller. Not like this.

Comment: Sanju thanks for the input.  I did create the model using EF.  Everything works if I access the data context in the controller class just like the example you provided, but if I try to use the data context in another class that is not a controller it throws error.  Reading the docs says use Iservice to call dbcontext service and add microsoft extension DI package, but this still throws error and says context is null.

Comment: Updated the answer to use DbContext using DI in the service classes (outside of controller classes).

Comment: Thanks it works now. I created interface class then register it in the startup.cs file.  One question do you have to have interface class or can you register your class without interface?

Comment: You can register it without Interface. Use `services.AddScoped<MyClass>();` I think it is good design pattern to use interfaces as `Interface` abstracts the actual implementation and you will be able to change implementation easily using interface without making any changes in the dependency requirements in calling class as they are depending on Interface.

Comment: @skjoshi In that last block of code in your answer, where/how is the `BlogsController` registered?

Comment: `BlogsController` is not registered anywhere for DI purpose. It is used by framework to provide response for the URLs under that controller.

Answer (score 0):

Like many people say (in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462139/access-context-in-an-asp-net-core-mvc-model?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well), accessing the Data Context in the Model is an anti-pattern in SOLID - but it may make sense in some projects.

One can inject the dependency [into the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2), followed by an injection to the Model.This prevents having to register a service for every Model.

The following example illustrates accessing the database from the Model for the View's dropdown values.

**View**:

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyClass
@inject MyDataContext db
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    MyClass tmp = new MyClass(db);
}

<!-- Markup... -->

<select asp-for="MyField" class="form-control" asp-items="tmp.MyModelFunc()"></select>
```

**Model**:

```
private readonly MyDataContext db;
public MyClass(MyDataContext context)
{
    db = context;
}

// class properties...    

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyModelFunc()
{
    List<SelectListItem> ddlb = db.MyClass.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ID, Text = x.name}).ToList();
    return new SelectList(ddlb , "Value", "Text");
}
```