# Access _context in an ASP.NET Core MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to interact with the database from within a Model in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC project.
Scaffolding has been used to create Controllers and views from the Models.

Ideally I would like to access it like I would in a controller with the _context but I failed finding a way to do so.

I also tried to create a new connection from the model:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext()){
    // Code here
}
```

But the ApplicationDbContext constructor requires options arguments like the default connection string which I failed retrieving from the config.

```
Public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {
}
```

My guess is that I misunderstand something very basic because this should be easy to do.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When I have to access, I access something like ** private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public YourController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }**

Comment: and then in controller action use  **_context.YourDBSET variable**

Comment: Do you use any dependency injection  tool?

Comment: I came across DI digging the internet for a solution. But this would mean pass _context to the class constructor right?

Comment: This is not something you should do; it would break the single responsibility principle of SOLID. However, this pretty much screams XY problem. What is it that you're *actually* trying to achieve? There's undoubtedly a better way.

Answer (score 3):

As others have told you, the way is use dependency injection.

Here is a real example (using postgresql):

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        #region PostgreSQL
        var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("your connection string name");

        // Use a PostgreSQL database
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(
                sqlConnectionString,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Your.Assembly.Name")
            )
        );
        #endregion

        ...
    }
```

In your controller (example of an api controller):

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/MyController")]
public class MyController : Controller
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DatasourceDataController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSometing()
    {
        ...
        await _context.(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Here you have a full example (you can scroll down to "Create the Database Context"): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

Hope it helps.

Comment: OP is trying to access the DataContext from the model, like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910650/how-do-i-access-datacontext-from-another-class-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks, I found this helpful - even if it may not have answered the original poster's question :-)